# CSS apply style with an Id selector

Tags: css

Is theres a way ***with css only*** to apply a specific style to an element when using an id selector inside a css ??

html:

```
<div Id="MyClassId"> blablabla </div>
```

css:

```
.MyOwnFancyDiv{
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #333333;
    /* ... */
}

/** 
 Select a particular element and need to apply the MyOwnFancyDiv style 
**/

#MyClassId{
    /* want to apply the MyOwnFancyDiv style to this particular element */
}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you saying you want to copy the styles from `.MyOwnFancyDiv` into `#MyClassId`?

Comment: The standard way is to add the class to the element with id. However, I presume that you can only change the CSS - see [Groups of selectors on one rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Groups_of_selectors_on_one_rule).

Comment: please can you *edit* your question and explain your problem more clearly -- id selectors are fundamental basic parts of CSS. I can't see what your problem is?

Comment: You cannot, using CSS alone, reference an existing rule's style without adding a selector to its declaration, or copy its properties.

Comment: @LGSon, alright, comments deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> I want to apply the MyOwnFancyDiv style to this particular element [the id element]

This can be done as specified -- only via CSS -- like so:

```
.MyOwnFancyDiv, 
#MyClassId {
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #333333;
    /* ... */
}
```

This will apply all style rules to each element specified (so the class `MyOwnFancyDiv` ***and*** the id element `MyClassId`.

This should solve your question.  If not, please can you edit and clarify the criteria and scope of your question. Thanks.